# LDAP filter to search for a DN

Tags: ldap

LDAP filters are powerful but I can't figure out how to search an object based on DN. Already I have many filter that searches for objects but searching for a specific DN does not seem to be supported.

So for example I have

```
&(objectclass=top)(uid=myspecialuser)(aci=*)
```

This will return an object with uid equal myspecialuser that has one or more `aci` attributes.

For reasons that I can't fully understand LDAP does not allow me to search for an object using DN for example

```
&(objectclass=top)(dn=cn=myspecialuser,o=special,c=NL)
```

In fact it doesn't seem possible to select objects at all using a filter without having an unique attribute to search for it. You cannot search for DN at all.

Is this correct? That there is no way to filter a search based on DN?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### a) All LDAP servers: Specify the DN as "base" for the search

The LDAP 'search' operation has a specific way to do this easily – not through filters, but **through the "base DN" parameter** (usually together with 'base' as the search scope).

For example, instead of your typical "subtree" search...

```
base: o=Special,c=NL
scope: sub
filter: (&(uid=myspecialuser)(aci=*))
```

...you would select a specific entry like this:

```
base: cn=My special user,o=Special,c=NL
scope: base
filter: (objectClass=*)
```

The 'base' scope prevents the search from returning any unwanted child entries, so you only get exactly the DN that you asked for.

(However, it doesn't add any magic besides that – you can specify any base with any scope.)

---

##### b) Some LDAP servers: Filterable operational attributes that mirror the DN

It is true that in *standard* LDAP you cannot write filters matching specific DNs, so if you wanted to retrieve multiple entries, you'd need to issue multiple 'base' search queries, one for each DN. (This isn't generally a problem because you can send a bunch of requests asynchronously, then await for all of them at once.)

However, **some** LDAP implementations do have custom operational attributes containing the entry's DN, which *can* be matched against.

- For example, [MS Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ada1/56da5a9b-485d-4d7c-a226-1a54a43d9013) has the `distinguishedName` operational attribute:

  ```
  filter: (|(distinguishedName=cn=My special user,o=Special,c=NL)
            (distinguishedName=cn=Other special user,o=Special,c=NL))
  ```
- OpenLDAP has the [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5020) `entryDN` operational attribute.
- 389 Directory Server *seems* to have `entryDN` but I haven't actually checked whether it can be searched against.

To see all operational attributes of an entry, just make a regular search but specify the `+` [wildcard](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/ldap-utils/ldapsearch.1.en.html#:%7E:text=If%20%2B%20is%20listed%2C%20all%20operational%20attributes%20are%20returned) in the "wanted attributes" parameter (instead of the usual `*`).

---

##### c) Some LDAP servers: Filtering on individual DN components

As a side note, there *is* a filter syntax (an [ExtensibleMatch](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch)) which allows matching against individual DN attributes just like they were entry attributes.

For example, `(o:dn:=Special)` would match all entries which have `o=Special` anywhere in their DN, even if it's not present in the entry itself, therefore matching all children of `o=Special`.

However, this is *not* widely supported; in particular you cannot use it with Active Directory (but you can in OpenLDAP).